# Trouble getting attributes into my build_order method for stripe payments

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, stripe-payments

I'm building a video marketplace where members can buy videos.
However I'm struggling to create the order so that it has the video_id, member_id and price.
This is my code:

Video model:

```
 has_many :members, through: :orders
 has_many :orders
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :orders
```

Member model:

```
  has_many :orders
  has_many :videos, through: :orders
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :orders
```

Order model:

```
attr_accessible :price, :stripe_card_token, :member_id, :video_id

  belongs_to :video
  belongs_to :member

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :video
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :member

    validates :member_id, presence: true
    validates :video_id, presence: true
    validates :price, presence: true

  attr_accessor :stripe_card_token

    def save_with_stripe
        video = @video.find_by_id(params[:id])
        member = @member.find_by_id(params[:id])
    if valid?
      @order = Stripe::Charge.create(
        amount: video.price,
        currency: "gbp",
        card: stripe_card_token,
        description: member.email
      )

      save!
    end
  rescue
    errors.add :base, "There was a problem with Stripe"
  end
```

Orders Controller:

```
def new
      @order = Order.new
      build_order
end

def create
  @order = Order.new(params[:order])
  if @order.save_with_stripe
      flash[:success] = "Enjoy the video!"
  else
    render partial: 'shared/buynow'
  end
end

def build_order
    @order.build_member(
      member_id: @member.id,
      video_id: @video.id,
      price: @video.price,    
      )
  end
```

I think my issue is somewhere in the "build_order" method, but I've tried various different ways and end up with various different errors.

```
It works in my console:

[221] pry(main)> Order.create(member_id: "36", video_id: "99", price: "1000")
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "orders" ("created_at", "member_id", "price", "stripe_card_token", "updated_at", "video_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Fri, 18 Oct 2013 14:50:09 UTC +00:00], ["member_id", 36], ["price", 1000], ["stripe_card_token", nil], ["updated_at", Fri, 18 Oct 2013 14:50:09 UTC +00:00], ["video_id", 99]]
   (0.5ms)  COMMIT
=> #<Order id: 3, video_id: 99, member_id: 36, stripe_card_token: nil, price: 1000, created_at: "2013-10-18 14:50:09", updated_at: "2013-10-18 14:50:09">
```

Any help on what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,
Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you trying to build a member object through the order?  Looks like you already have the member and video, so why not just pass the same hash of values in to the call to new?

e.g.

```
@order = Order.new(member_id: @member.id, video_id: @video.id, price: @video.price)
```